Parfor "Out of Memory during deserialization" in large matrix operations
I am trying to use parfor for a large matrix operation. I am getting Out of Memory during deserialization error. Is there a way to minimize the memory? Below is the minimal example code:
clc; clear;
warpedImages = num2cell(uint8(randi([0,255], 1654, 6288, 3, 35)),1:3);
warpedImages = reshape(warpedImages,1,[]);
% Initialze
n = length(warpedImages);
sigmaN = 10;
sigmag = 0.1;
panoramasize = size(warpedImages{1});
Amat = cell(n);
Bvec = zeros(n,1);   
IuppeIdx = nonzeros(triu(reshape(1:numel(Amat), size(Amat))));
Amat_temp = cell(1,length(IuppeIdx));    
matSize = size(Amat);
    
% 4D warped images (Slicing)
wim_4d = cell2mat(reshape(warpedImages,1,1,1,[]));
% Get the Ibarijs and Nijs
parfor i = 1:length(IuppeIdx)
    % Index to subscripts
    [ii,jj] = ind2sub(matSize, IuppeIdx(i));                 
    if ii == jj
        diag_val_1 = 0;
        diag_val_2 = 0;
       
        Z = 1:n;
        Z(Z==ii) = [];
        for d = Z
            [Ibarij, Ibarji, Nij] = getIbarNij(panoramasize, wim_4d(:,:,:,ii), wim_4d(:,:,:,d));
            diag_val_1 = diag_val_1 + ( (Nij + Nij) .*  Ibarij.^2 );
            diag_val_2 = diag_val_2 + Nij;
        end
        diag_val = diag_val_1 + (sigmaN^2/sigmag^2) * diag_val_2;
        B_val = (sigmaN^2/sigmag^2) * diag_val_2;
        Amat_temp{i} = diag_val;
        Bvec(i) = B_val
    end       
    if ii ~= jj
        [Ibarij,Ibarji,Nij] = getIbarNij(panoramasize, wim_4d(:,:,:,ii), wim_4d(:,:,:,jj));
        Amat_temp{i} = -(Nij+Nij) .* (Ibarij .* Ibarji);
    end
end
function [Ibarij,Ibarji,Nij] = getIbarNij(panoramasize, Imij, Imji)
    Ibarij = zeros(panoramasize,'uint8');
    Ibarji = zeros(panoramasize,'uint8');
    
    % Overlay the warpedImage onto the panorama.
    maski = imbinarize(rgb2gray(255 * Imij));  
    maskj = imbinarize(rgb2gray(255 * Imji));
    
    % Find the overlap mask
    Nij_im  = maski & maskj;
    Nij_im  = imfill(Nij_im, 'holes');    
    Nijidx = repmat(Nij_im, 1, 1, size(Imij,3));
    
    % Get the overlapping region RGB values for two images
    Ibarij(Nijidx) = Imij(Nijidx);
    Ibarji(Nijidx) = Imji(Nijidx);
    
    % Convert to double
    Ibarij_double = double(Ibarij);
    Ibarji_double = double(Ibarji);
    
    % Nij
    Nij = sum(sum(Nij_im));
    
    % Ibar ijs
    Ibarij = reshape(sum(sum(Ibarij_double)) ./ Nij, 1, 3);
    Ibarji = reshape(sum(sum(Ibarji_double)) ./ Nij, 1, 3); 
    
    % Replace NaNs by zeros
    Ibarij(isnan(Ibarij)) = 0;
    Ibarji(isnan(Ibarji)) = 0;
end

Line [Ibarij, Ibarji, Nij] = getIbarNij(panoramasize, wim_4d(:,:,:,ii), wim_4d(:,:,:,d)); throws a warning message: The entire array or structure 'wim_4d' is a broadcast variable. This might result in unnecessary communication overhead. I have used ind2sub for getting the subscripts as it is easy to work. However, wim_4d(:,:,:,ii) and others cannot be sliced. Any other suggestion and help is appreciated!

you probably can use fewer variables in getIbarNij function. Also have your tried reading your images inside the loop instead of reading them outside and assigning a huge 4-dimensional matrix for it?

Even if I read the images in parfor loop, I cannot slice wim_4d(:,:,:,ii). Because it is using the subscripts.

I suggest using a Thread Pool for this - i.e. run parpool('Threads') before running your code.
One of the advantages of Thread Pool is that it can be more memory efficient, especially with parfor broadcast data (as is the case for wim_4d). Using a process pool, each worker needs its own separate copy of that 1Gb array; using a thread pool, the workers automatically use an efficient shared-memory copy.

if I use the parpool('Threads') vision library functions, it throws an error saying that Threads is not supported. Error using detectSIFTFeatures>checkImage Use of function _visionIsObject is not supported on a thread-based worker.

Which version are you using? Support for running on a thread worker is added for new functions all the time. It seemed OK when I ran in R2024a.

I am using R2023a.

The code as posted runs successfully in R2023a - but it doesn't use detectSIFTFeatures. Unfortunately, that function isn't supported on thread pool (even in R2024a).

Try the following code, where I've simplified your getIbarNij function and I'm generating the images inside the loop, you can replace random matrices with your image read function.
clc; clear;

% Initialze
n = 35;
sigmaN = 10;
sigmag = 0.1;
Amat = cell(n);
Bvec = zeros(n,1);   
IuppeIdx = nonzeros(triu(reshape(1:numel(Amat), size(Amat))));
Amat_temp = cell(1,length(IuppeIdx));    
matSize = size(Amat);

% Get the Ibarijs and Nijs
parfor i = 1:length(IuppeIdx)
    % Index to subscripts
    [ii,jj] = ind2sub(matSize, IuppeIdx(i));
    imgii=uint8(randi([0,255], 1654, 6288, 3));
    if ii == jj
        diag_val_1 = 0;
        diag_val_2 = 0;
       
        Z = 1:n;
        Z(Z==ii) = [];
        for d = Z
            imgd=uint8(randi([0,255], 1654, 6288, 3));
            [Ibarij, Ibarji, Nij] = getIbarNij( imgii, imgd);
            diag_val_1 = diag_val_1 + ( (Nij + Nij) .*  Ibarij.^2 );
            diag_val_2 = diag_val_2 + Nij;
        end
        diag_val = diag_val_1 + (sigmaN^2/sigmag^2) * diag_val_2;
        B_val = (sigmaN^2/sigmag^2) * diag_val_2;
        Amat_temp{i} = diag_val;
        Bvec(i) = B_val
    else
        imgjj=uint8(randi([0,255], 1654, 6288, 3));
        [Ibarij,Ibarji,Nij] = getIbarNij(imgii, imgjj);
        Amat_temp{i} = -(Nij+Nij) .* (Ibarij .* Ibarji);
    end
end
function [Ibarij,Ibarji,Nij] = getIbarNij(Imij, Imji)
    
    % Overlay the warpedImage onto the panorama.
    maski = imbinarize(rgb2gray(255 * Imij));  
    maskj = imbinarize(rgb2gray(255 * Imji));
    
    % Find the overlap mask
    Nij_im  = maski & maskj;
    Nij_im  = imfill(Nij_im, 'holes');    
    
    % Get the overlapping region RGB values for two images
    Imij=Imij(:);
    Imij=Imij([Nij_im(:);Nij_im(:);Nij_im(:)]);
    Imji=Imji(:);
    Imji=Imji([Nij_im(:);Nij_im(:);Nij_im(:)]);

    % Nij
    Nij = sum(sum(Nij_im));
    
    % Ibar ijs
    Ibarij = sum(reshape(Imij,[], 3))/Nij;
    Ibarji = sum(reshape(Imji,[], 3))/Nij; 
    
    % Replace NaNs by zeros
    Ibarij(isnan(Ibarij)) = 0;
    Ibarji(isnan(Ibarji)) = 0;
end


thank you! I cannot generate an image like this, a cell array contains W = 1 to n images. I need to slice it according to the subscripts [ii,jj]. However, using these subscripts would broadcast the whole W cell array. This is the problem.
